# How to deploy a PyPI Server in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pypiserver

I'm trying with [PyPICloud](https://pypi.org/project/pypicloud/)  on the .yaml file  there is this config

```
runtime: python37
service: dev-pypyserver
instance_class: F4

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
  
default_expiration: "3s"



entrypoint: pserve server.ini
```

but the logs say: "failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart()"

Answer (score 2):

From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime

> The entrypoint should start a web server that listens on the port specified by the `PORT` environment variable.

By default, `pypicloud` uses port `6543` which is likely not the same port that the runtime is asking you to use.